# Pandas connect to Oracle Db without connection string

Tags: python, oracle, pandas, connection-string, cx-oracle

I need to read data form an Oracle db (with pandas).
I'm using the cx_oracle libraries. The tutorial suggest to use this instruction to create a connection:

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, connectString)
```

I don't have the connection string but the host, db_name, user and password.
How can I create a connection or how can I create the connection string?

**Edit:**
I have:

- host Name
- Port
- Service Name (not the SID)
- User & Pwd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need below variables(IP, PORT, SID,USERNAME, PASSWORD). Once you create the cursor, you can use it to insert as well as query the DB.

```
def dbquery(query_db, cred_db):
    """
    This function queries the Database
    """
    curs = cred_db.cursor()
    curs.execute(query_db)
    rows = curs.fetchall()
    curs.close()
    return rows

connectString= cx_Oracle.makedsn(IP, PORT, SID)
DB_CRED = cx_Oracle.connect(USERNAME, PASSWORD, connectString)
QUERY = "SELECT * FROM something WHERE blah blah"
RES = dbquery(QUERY, DB_CRED)
```

Use above code, just assign your query to QUERY variable

Comment: I do not have sid but the service name.

Comment: I found the SID with 'select instance from v$thread;'
Now, how I use the cursor with pandas?

Comment: have modified the answer to include function which uses cursor

Comment: For service names, use `connectString= cx_Oracle.makedsn(IP, PORT, service_name=SERVICENAME)`

Answer (score -1):

Try Oracle's Easy Connect syntax:

```
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, 'HOSTNAME:PORT/SERVICENAME')
```

See Oracle documentation [Understanding the Easy Connect Naming Method](https://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=dblatest&id=GUID-B0437826-43C1-49EC-A94D-B650B6A4A6EE).

Or use:

```
connectString = cx_Oracle.makedsn(IP, PORT, service_name=SERVICENAME)
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(username, password, connectString)
```